# Three JS - How to access the object loaded from .obj by name?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I got a function which loads objects from .obj files this way:

```
function loadObject(obj, mtl, clr, opc, px, py, pz, rx, ry, rz, cs, rs, name) {
    switch(mtl) {
        case 'transparent':
            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                color: clr,
                transparent: true,
                opacity: opc,
            });
            break;
        case 'web':
            var material = createElementMaterial('img/web.png');
            break;
        case 'basic':
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: clr });
            break;
        default:
            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: clr, transparent: true, opacity: opc});
            break;
    }
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.load(obj, function(mesh) {
        globalobject = mesh;
        globalobject.name = name;
        mesh.traverse(function(node) {
            if(node instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                node.castShadow = cs;
                node.receiveShadow = rs;
                node.material = material;
                node.position.x = px;
                node.position.y = py;
                node.position.z = pz;
                node.rotation.x = rx;
                node.rotation.y = ry;
                node.rotation.z = rz;           }
        });
        scene.add(mesh);
    });
}
```

Now, I need to name each loaded object and control its properties such as opacity etc. by using getObjectByName(). The objects get loaded and follow the function rules but when I load an object and try to access it by name, I get an undefined output from console and it's when I can print the object when I send query to console by typing in it directly.
So, in another hand, I'm looking for a way which allows me to access each loaded object from .obj files.

Comment: You can use the traverse method.. like so:

scene.traverse( (o)=>console.log(o.name) )

Comment: And for example in a code like mine, how one can access the object created and named as 'home'?

Comment: You are already saving a reference in `globalobject`, why not make this object store all the references with something like `globalobject[name] = mesh`, then you could easily get your objects without having to call `getObjectByName`. You would just get your object with `globalobject.home`.

Comment: globalobject is defined inside the load function. I didn't completely understand  the idea of getting accessed from outside the function.

Comment: scene.getObjectByName('home')

Comment: scene.getObjectByName('home') does not working as explained

Comment: .OBJ format doesn't support multiple objects per file, and it doesn't support object transforms. You should use a more modern format like .GLTF to get full scenes/materials/textures etc.

As far as scene.getObjectByName("home") not working.. you have a bug in your code.. and you didn't list the code that has the bug.

Answer (score -1):

```
var object = scene.getObjectByName( "objectName" );
```

Comment: Hi! Please add some explanation as to how this solves OP's problem. It is generally discouraged on SO to post code only answers as they do not help OP or future visitors understand the answer. Thanks! --From Review.

Comment: It won't fix OPs problem.. it's just the necessary function call. OPs problem is a bug in his code elsewhere. 11 months ago... cheers!